# Iterate through array and remove certain string elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, nokogiri

I'm parsing an html page with nokogiri and extracting some data points. It seems to extract the correct data points, but also extracts nulls and comma's, here's a sample of whats extracted :

```
null,
3.28,
null,
null,
null,
1.91,
2.83,
null,
9.06,
null,
3.80,
6.42,
null,
```

I want to be able to remove all instances of "null," as well as commas in general and then convert each element to a float. The above doesn't seem to be removing "null," at all.

Comment: Do an `array.inspect` to check for non-printing characters. Or change the `x == "null,"` to `x =~ /null.*$/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do:

```
array.reject{|x|x =~ /null/}.map(&:to_f)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work even with this, what's more I get undefined method to_f for ["null"] Array. What could this be?

Comment: Still the same problem, it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't get rid of the null part either.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to do something with the result. The original array is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
input = <<INPUT
null,
3.28,
null,
null,
null,
1.91,
2.83,
null,
9.06,
null,
3.80,
6.42,
null,
INPUT

result = input.split.map(&:to_f)
=> [0.0, 3.28, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.91, 2.83, 0.0, 9.06, 0.0, 3.8, 6.42, 0.0]
result.delete(0.0)
=> 0.0
result
=> [3.28, 1.91, 2.83, 9.06, 3.8, 6.42]
```

Comment: this would also remove any 0's that might be in the input

Comment: True. But OP hasn't claimed, that he need zeros :)

Comment: He didn't claim he needed fours or fives either. I think the code should handle them.

Answer (score 0):

excluding commas (note the bracket in the regular expression):

```
data1 =  inline.to_s().scan(/y: (.*?)\,/)
```

the result:

```
result = data1.reject{|item| item == "null"}.map(&:to_f)
```